# The column of the csv file in google automl tables is recognised as text or categorical instead of numeric as i would like

Tags: google-cloud-automl

I tried to train a model using google automl tables but i have the following problem

The csv file is correctly imported, it has 2 columns and about 1870 rows, all numeric.
The system recognises only 1 column as numeric but not the other.
The column, where the problem is, has 5 digits in each row separated with space.

Is there anything i should do in order for the system to properly recognise the data as numeric?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the Data type [Numeric](https://cloud.google.com/automl-tables/docs/data-types#numeric) definition, the number needs to be comparable (greater than, smaller than, equal).

Two different list of numbers are not comparable, for example 2 4 7 is not comparable to 1 5 7. To solve this, without using strings and therefore losing the "information" of those numbers, you have several options.

For example:

- Create an array of numbers, by inserting [ ] in the limits of the second entrance. Take into consideration the [Array](https://cloud.google.com/automl-tables/docs/data-types#array) Data type relative weighted approach in AutoMl tables as it may affect the "information" extracted from the sequence.
- Create additional columns for every entry of the second column so each one is a single number and hence truly numeric.

I would personally go for the second option.

If you are afraid of losing "information" by splitting the numbers take into consideration that after training, the model should deduce by itself the importance of the position and other "information" those number sequences might contain (mean, norm/modulus,relative increase,...) provided the training data is representative.